# Cross site session creation with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session, devise

I'm working on a project that uses sessions to manage the currently logged in user with a slight twist, there is no log in form on the actual application.  Instead, another site will provide a button that should log in the user and redirect to their profile page.

For example, the customer is viewing their profile on Site A, the 3rd party application.  From their profile on Site A they click on a button that should log them in to Site B and redirect to their profile on Site B, the site I'm building.

I'm a unfamiliar with the security concerns for a case like this.  My initial thought is that if Site A POSTs via https the user's email address and password, then it should work just as if they were filling the form out on my site, Site B.

What security concerns am I missing here or will this just not work at all?

NOTE: The 3rd party site is basically out of my hands and I'll never convince that team to setup any sort of OAuth protocol, or at the very least its going to take unacceptably long. Plus, OAuth, at least with my understanding is method to accept requests from any number of 3rd parties.  No other site except for SiteA will ever attempt to log people in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a typical application for an OAuth provider.

Get an overview and grasp the concept here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oauth

There already exists OAuth Providers in Ruby, so you don't have to do everything by yourself: e.g. https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider.

**But** if you really wanna do this without, then I would let the other server generate a hash containing the users id (can be username, email, or database id), a random token, the current timestamp and then sign this using [MessageVerifier](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html). Then you can check on your server if the timestamp is within a certain range (some minutes) and if the message verifies (using the same key naturally). If so, then accept the user.

If the other site uses PHP, then you might have to rebuild the `generate` method in PHP. Find the source in Ruby [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1f80e8d6856837dd78a4af756e1b26cf06b17fc2/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb#L51).

Comment: See my comment above.  I know OAuth is the "correct" solution, but I am super skeptical that ever happens.

Comment: So you will basically re-implement OAuth in your own system, a process which will need much time and in which you are guaranteed to rip open some security holes. Tell them they have to set up OAuth...

Comment: And when they say absolutely not, what then?  Plus, I think OAuth is big time overkill here.  OAuth is about authenticating the 3rd party site that wants to access your app.  I don't need to authenticate the 3rd party, its always the same site. What if I just issued them a token that I required to authenticate them, kind of like an API token?

Comment: You are the 3rd party application regarding OAuth... But if you really wanna do this without, then I would let the other server generate a hash containing the users id (can be username, email, or database id), a random token, the current timestamp and then sign this using [MessageVerifier](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageVerifier.html). Then you can check on your server if the timestamp is within a certain range (some minutes) and if the message verifies (using the same key naturally). If so, then accept the user.

Comment: That creates a strict Base64 encoding which I assume they'll be able to generate in their PHP app. Thanks.